# I cannot paste Rstudio console output into Excel anymore

Tags: r, excel, copy-paste

So previously, when I ran statistics in R, I was able to copy and paste to Excel works sheet (for example rstudio console window output), but now it seems like there is a problem. When I now press paste (or ctrl+v), it just leaves it empty and nothing is pasted into the worksheet. It works if I paste it to notepad first and then copy and paste it to Excel.

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: Please provide an example of what exactly you want to copy to Excel.

Answer (score 1):

It might depend on the object you are trying to paste. From my experience it works well with standard classes from R, e.g. copying the output of:

```
data.frame(A=c("cats","dogs","pig"), B=c("kittens","puppies","pig"))
```

from the console to Excel works fine.

However, if I convert to something from the tidyverse, e.g.

```
tibble(A=c("cats","dogs","pig"), B=c("kittens","puppies","pig"))
```

it doesn't copy nicely anymore. One solution is to not directly paste into Excel, but use the "paste" button, then "paste special", then choose "unicode text".

Some reference here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/paste-special-e03db6c7-8295-4529-957d-16ac8a778719

Comment: yes, the script copys and pastes okey, but if run lm and then want to copy that result, it dose nothing. How do i fix that?

Comment: copying an lm result works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when trying to copy/paste a tibble, but making it into a data.frame solves the issue. The output from this:

```
a <- c("abc",9238)
b <- c("def",123)
tibble(a,b)
```

shows up blank when I copy/paste, but this gives console output that works:

```
tibble(a,b) %>% data.frame()
```